# Что такое полиморфизм

Tags: c++, ооп

"Полиморфизм это способность обеспечить один и тот же интерфейс для классов с разной реализацией. Он помогает упростить код с помощью абстракции."

Можете подробно объяснить, что такое полиморфизм в контексте ООП. Зачем он нужен, какую проблему решает. Какая его связь с абстракцией? Когда использовать статический, а когда динамический?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Читайте книги по ООП.

Comment: Полиморфизм является своего рода дополнением инкапсуляции. **Инкапсуляция** представляет объект в виде чёрного ящика с «рычажками», посредством которых которых можно управлять этим ящиком. **Полиморфизм** же идёт дальше, позволяя не задумываться о том, куда эти «рычажки» ведут и чем вообще является управляемый ящик.